# What are examples of hot and cold signal in ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: ios, signals, reactive-cocoa

In this answer [How to make RACSignal to become hot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22204188/1418457), @erikprice explains hot and cold signal

> A "hot signal" is a signal that sends values (and presumably does
>   work) regardless of whether it has any subscribers. A "cold signal" is
>   a signal that defers its work and the sending of any values until it
>   has a subscriber. And a cold signal will perform its work and send
>   values for each subscriber.

I ask if someone can demonstrate examples of hot and cold signals, so that it will be clearer

Comment: Maybe this answers a bit http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/an-introduction-to-reactivecocoa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A hot signal is considered to be a signal that sends values regardless of whether it has any subscribers

I am using a hot signal for monitoring network reachability. A button action realized through `RACCommand` is another example of hot signal.

> A "cold signal" is a signal that defers its work and the sending of any values until it has a subscriber.

This one is very well demonstrated by making AFNetworking reactive. Create a method that returns a signal representing a request. Whenever you subscribe to that signal, the networking request is performed. The subscriber is being `sendNext:` and `sendCompleted` when request is successful and `sendError:` when request fails.

Answer (score 8):

I find the [RAC 3 Changelog](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/v4.0-alpha.1/CHANGELOG.md) to be useful, too

**Hot signals are now Signals**

> In the terminology of RAC 2, a “hot” RACSignal does not trigger any
>   side effects when a -subscribe… method is called upon it. In other
>   words, hot signals are entirely producer-driven and push-based, and
>   consumers (subscribers) cannot have any effect on their lifetime.
>
> This pattern is useful for notifying observers about events that will
>   occur no matter what. For example, a loading boolean might flip
>   between true and false regardless of whether anything is observing it.
>
> Concretely, every RACSubject is a kind of hot signal, because the
>   events being forwarded are not determined by the number of subscribers
>   on the subject.

**Cold signals are now SignalProducers**

> In the terminology of RAC 2, a “cold” RACSignal performs its work one
>   time for every subscription. In other words, cold signals perform side
>   effects when a -subscribe… method is called upon them, and may be able
>   to cancel in-progress work if -dispose is called upon the returned
>   RACDisposable.
>
> This pattern is broadly useful because it minimizes unnecessary work,
>   and allows operators like take, retry, concat, etc. to manipulate when
>   work is started and cancelled. Cold signals are also similar to how
>   futures and promises work, and can be useful for structuring
>   asynchronous code (like network requests).

I have written [Push vs Pull Signal](http://www.fantageek.com/blog/2016/01/03/push-vs-pull-signal/) which basically reveal how Push vs Pull Signal get implemented, in Swift 2