# How to Accomplish this w/ ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm building a feature where users of my app can find their Facebook friends and add them in the app. There are three steps which I have to do:

1. Get the currently connected users
2. Get the Facebook users
3. Get the Application Users (this is dependent on step 2)

Once all of these complete I then need to combine/reduce the three resulting arrays into a final array.

I have created three functions that all return `RACSignal`

`getUsersWithFacebookIds`, `getConnectedUsers`, and `getFacebookUsers`

I'm not sure how to wire all of this using ReactiveCocoa.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Once All Are Done Do Something With All`, can be achieve with:

```
[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[connectUsersSignal,facebookUsersSignal,applicationUsersSignal]] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *users) {
    NSArray *connectedUsers = [users first];
    NSArray *facebookUsers = [users second];
    NSArray *applicationUsers = [users third];

}];
```

The other piece missing is how you make the `applicationUsersSignal` dependent on the `facbookUsersSignal`. Which could be done like this:

```
- (RACSignal *)applicationUsersSignalWithFacebookUsersSignal:(RACSignal *)fbSignal
{
    return [fbSignal flattenMap:^RACStream *(NSArray *facebookUsers) {
        return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
            // Do what you have to do with the facebookUsers
            return nil;
        }];
    }];
}
```

Just to add a bit more to the answer. I am assuming those are cold signals, (signals that haven't started yet aka haven't been subscribed). So the idea of using `combineLatest:` is that you want to capture the point where each and every single signal as send at least one `next`, [after that you subscribe to it so it can begin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22204188/491239). Finally you can get their values from a `RACTuple`.

---

I re read your question and you want them to come all in a single Array:

```
[[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[connectUsersSignal,facebookUsersSignal,applicationUsersSignal]] map:^id(RACTuple *allArrays) {
    return [allArrays.rac_sequence foldLeftWithStart:[NSMutableArray array] reduce:^id(id accumulator, id value) {
        [accumulator addObjectsFromArray:value];
        return accumulator;
    }];
}] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *allUsers) {
    // Do Something
}];
```

Comment: It seems that the last code snippet can be simplified using `combineLatest:reduce`

Comment: @MichałCiuba you would get 3 arrays in the `combineLatest:reduce:`, which is different from getting all 3 arrays flattened into one.

Comment: @RuiAAPeres You can use `combineLatest:reduce:` to avoid the `allArrays.first`, `allArrays.second`, etc calls. But in this case, you can just get an `rac_sequence` from the tuple itself, and `map` remains the appropriate operation.

Comment: @RuiAAPeres I meant something like this: https://gist.github.com/mciuba/9e8c6f31408a336b3749. I did a simple test and it seems to send the same array in `subscribeNext` block as with your code sample. Are there any differences I can't see?

Comment: @MichałCiuba the problem with that solution, is that if I had a new Signal that returns an array, the `reduce` won't flat its elements. With a `fold` you don't have that issue.